Advice needed: Team needs developers, but company isn't posting jobs
I'm facing a challenging situation at work and need advice on professional conduct:

Manager requested 5+ developers from the board
Company has no job ads on any platform
Manager and team agree: 3+ developers urgently needed to complete projects
Company is narrowing operations this year
Leadership seems to disagree on recruitment
I only have direct contact with my manager; he offered to relay my suggestions to HR

As a team member, I'm concerned about project timelines and workload, but I'm not in a position to advise leadership directly.
Questions:

How can I professionally address these concerns without overstepping?
What strategies can improve team efficiency given our current staffing?
How to support my manager's staffing efforts while respecting company decisions?

Any advice on navigating this situation professionally would be appreciated.

Are project deadlines negotiable? Is scope negotiable?

@Bogdan yes, the project is behind schedule. We aim to provide the main contractor with a new target date by which we expect to catch up and no longer be delayed. Scope is fixed, end the project :) We try to finish it in 3 months, have not notified the contractor about the new calendar yet, as I know.

Yes, but does it run crisis mode? That`s what the setup smells like :)


How can I professionally address these concerns without overstepping?

It sounds like you already are. You say your boss has offered to convey your concerns to HR, so it sounds like you're already expressing your concerns around timelines.

What strategies can improve team efficiency given our current staffing?

That is way too broad for anyone here who doesn't know your company, your team or your work to be able to answer. If you have concerns about workload, thinking about efficiencies and trying to improve it is definitely something to do. Just avoid "efficiencies" like "doing free overtime" or " do more tickets all at once"

How to support my manager's staffing efforts while respecting company decisions?

Ultimately the leadership are going to make the staffing decisions, all you can do is provide information to your boss around what you think the result of the understaffing is. Maybe you'll provide the key bit of evidence that convinces them or maybe they'll decide to keep current staffing levels either because they have context you don't or maybe just because they're wrong. But you can't really do more than that.
EDIT As Mark Rotteveel points out below, it isn't obvious what expressing your concerns to HR is going to do. They wouldn't normally be involved in project allocation. Maybe he's telling them his team is unhappy, maybe he's telling them that his manager is ignoring concerns around delivery. But the important part though is that you've told your boss and it's up to him to decide how best to convey that up the chain of command.

I'm not sure what conveying concerns to HR will achieve though. HR may be responsible for recruitment, but they are - generally - not responsible for deciding to recruit and the actual allocation of personnel across teams and departments.

"But you can't really do more than that." -- Personally, I'd add a recommendation to make sure OP's CV is up-to-date. Just to be prepared in case the situation blows up when timelines will not be met (which sounds to happen pretty certainly).

Beware of "fire the unhappy people" solutions  - they might seem unironic to some!


3+ developers urgently needed to complete projects

We all know urgent recruitment of developers doesn't work, unless you're able and willing to bring in an army of new analysts and developers with vastly more experience of everything, and relegating the in-house team to mere spectators who have no duties other than being pumped for business-specific information.
There's such a long ramp-up time for new developers, and such a communication overhead for the existing staff, that it is usually a massive mistake to try recruitment to solve a shortage.
Instead, demand should be immediately curtailed to suit existing resources, and recruitment planned for after the essential urgent work is complete and the crisis is over.

How can I professionally address these concerns without overstepping?

Well there can be no suggestion of overstepping simply by advising your manager that given available resources, most currently planned work will be late or will never arrive.

What strategies can improve team efficiency given our current staffing?

Probably none. A time of crisis of resource and pressure of impending lateness, is not a good time to be innovating your own work methods, unless you were already aware of a huge inefficiencies or overheads yourself and could simply drop them immediately.

How to support my manager's staffing efforts while respecting company decisions?

Simply do a fair day's work and let the results be what they will be.
You might also want to invite your manager to consider priorities now and help him digest what is important and what can be dropped.

I was surprised to go through all existing answers before the "Mythical Man Month" was finally mentioned. Adding more people to a late project makes it even more late, in the short-term.

This. 100% what MatthieuM said. I’ve seen more bodies thrown at a behind-schedule project just make it more behind schedule on several occasions, and I’ve never ever seen it work.

I agree with the overall answer but this: "until [...] the crisis is over", because the crisis is NEVER over.

"and relegating the in-house team to mere spectators who have no duties other than being pumped for business-specific information." Way to cause a mess that you won't recover from usually. There's an even worse variation: New staff was hired due to inflated resumes/skills. They won't cut it. Original develops will feel offended and either quit in droves or mutineer and drive your new staff out.

@rackandboneman, quote is certainly not something I advise, or which is usually economically possible. Really just trying to illustrate the extremes to which a business would have to go.


"I only have direct contact with my manager; he offered to relay my suggestions to HR".

That is good enough. You already did a good job that a responsible team member can do.
You are not a team lead or manager. So, you should simply follow the "chain of command" for now.
This means that you should just let your manager take over this "project and staffing planning" task from here. It is your manager's job to deal with HR, his own boss, and other stakeholders. Your manager has the responsibility, duty, and authority to carry out this task.
You should not go further and should not interact with HR, your manager's boss, or other stakeholders (without your manager's request).

If your manager ask you to help him with the planning, then you can do anything he asks you to do. Otherwise, let him do his job.

Good answer but your Manager needs hard facts - this is what we can do with current staffing levels, these are the dates when projects will be delivered etc etc. Then do the same with your desired staffing level.

Been there, done that.  Here's what I recommend:

DO NOT WORK OVERTIME
This will only encourage upper management and bean counters to do their faulty scheduling.  If they know your team can work overtime once, they know that you can do it more often.
Record, save copies
All correspondence between your team and the stakeholders should be recorded and make backups.  Verify that all correspondence has dates.  You could print, then scan for better defense.
Offer to provide better estimates
One of your jobs is to provide {more} accurate development time estimates.  Do not use calendar time, use duration.  Alert stakeholders "frequently", like once a week, so they have the ammunition to change schedules and plans.  Again, document these estimates and when they were sent out.  Remember, you estimates are wild guesses at the beginning and become more accurate towards the end of the project.
Remind the management to reduce requirements
Projects with fewer requirements get produced faster.  Usually the skipped requirements can be appended after project or sprint is finished.
Debugging The Development Process by Steve McConnell
Steve is from Microsoft and has plenty of project experience and tells how to deal with most project issues in this book.
Hiring must take place near the beginning of the project.
As stated by Steve, adding resources in the midst of a project usually extends the duration of the project.  Let management and stakeholders know that adding more resources can reduce a project's duration, and show them how long the last project duration was.
DO NOT CAVE.  Be prepared to offer alternatives.
I'm not saying to stand your ground and "just say no", but to stand your ground and offer suggestions or compromises.  Speak in terms of money and duration; never discuss in calendar time.
Have your team take a project management course.
Divide your tasks into smaller pieces.
If you have a task that requires 6 people, divide it into pieces that smaller team can accomplish.  If management or stakeholders complain, remind them that hiring more people, (obtaining more resources) can shorten the development duration. :-)


The other thing you can do is work with your lead and team to triage the issues and make sure you are focused on addressing the most critical concerns -- and the ones you can complete before the targeted release date -- first.
The concept of "minimum shippable product" is useful here. As is distinguishing between important and urgent, and starting with the issues that are both.

Meanwhile, practice the phrase "sure, I can do that; what should we delay so I have the time to do it?" This will come in useful if management asks you to do more work than can possibly be squeezed into the time available.

Be very cautious
If your concerns are relayed to HR this helps nothing. It has to go up the "chain of command", not to HR. They only do what is being told to them, they do not decide if or how many people are going to be recruited.
Professional advise:

Very closely monitor your workload in the next time.

Make written notes about work hours.

Also take a subjective note on the felt impact of work, how exhausted you are after each day, what your stress levels are and if you feel comfortable or not.



Find a new job and prepare to quit the old one.

Evaluate your written notes from time to time. Especially when things get stressful. Is this an ongoing trend only worsening? That is the track to burn-out. -> Leave.


If you want to inform management about the unsustainable workload, you can. But do not think your input changes the situation. Management will not change, even if you repeatedly tell them (They know what they are doing/demanding, don't think they need your input to get it). Either they change by themselves and you do not need to say a word, or they won't. Be prepared to leave or burn out!

It would be unprofessional by management if they just offer more money but do nothing against the workload. It would also be unprofessional/irresponsible from you to just ask for more money and try to hold up against the increasing workload.

Professionalism is not slavery. You are allowed to go and you should go if you can't stand it.



You did all you should have. Besides the weekly reminders that you need people I'd start looking for a new job yourself. Because there's two reasons why your company is not hiring:

It can't afford to hire anyone and is on a brink of bankruptcy
Management is intentionally squeezing you dry and will be forcing you into unpaid overtime

Either way the situation will sooner or later implode - either you will work yourself to the brink and resign so they can replace you with a new victim, or the company will collapse leaving you jobless.

The best thing you and the team can do is:

to come in to the office on time daily
do the work at a normal rate with proper due diligence
take your breaks and lunch period consistently
go home on time
take your vacation time/sick time as you need it
SET REALISTIC EXPECTATIONS with your management on work the company needs performed.

You should have no one trying to be some sort of superhero to save this company from the rut it's in.  If management wants the work done more quickly, it will have no choice but to respond in kind by hiring more people.  On the other hand, if your team decides to play superhero and "suck it up", that's a disincentive for management to hire more staff because management will figure that everybody's okay in such a role.  This latter situation is the quickest route to burnout and people quitting once they decide they can't take it any more.

Take your concerns to your boss, make a case for more staff. Then you have discharged your professional duty.
It sounds like you've done this.
Now you have to decide what you're going to do if they don't bring in enough people.  Here are some scenarios:

They hire no one and deadlines can be met without undue strain
hard work is ok.

They hire no one, deadlines are impossible, and they expect you to work overtime for pay.
How much are they going to pay you for, say, an extra 20 hours a week?

They hire no one, deadlines are impossible, and they expect you to work unpaid overtime indefinitely until the projects are done.
Managers are rewarded in most companies for wringing as much work as possible from the staff. If you and a co-worker each work 20 hours a week extra, for free, then the manager has just saved the company $150,000 a year plus a headhunter's finder's fee.


You need to decide what you're going to do in these cases.

"Managers are rewarded ... for wringing as much work as possible from the staff ... 20 hours a week extra ... saved [salary] ... [no] finder's fee" - it would be easy to find managers with that thinking, but fewer examples of where that thinking has worked!

It works in the short term, managers do it all the time.

How short? I mean a couple of hours responding to an out-of-hours emergency, is very different from enforcing 20 hours more a week, indefinitely in a manner that actually saves a salary on project work.

I know of several cases where the manager wrung extra work out of the team - only to have the best members of the team find other jobs.

I'm not sure why this answer is getting downvoted.
